# Print a declared variable in trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms, database-trigger

I want to count the number of tuples inserted after each inserted statement and display, is there any possible way to get that done?

code:

```
mysql> create trigger count_inserted_trigger
    -> after insert on employee
    -> for each row
    -> begin
    -> declare count_it int;
    -> set count_it  = 0;
    -> set count_it  = count_it + 1;
    -> select count_it;
    -> end;
    -> $$
```

error:

ERROR 1415 (0A000): Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easier way would be to count the "rows affected" after your INSERT is done.

Every MySQL API should have a method for this. For example PHP's [PDOStatement::rowCount()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php). Even if you are running the INSERT from an SQL script or a stored procedure, you can use the MySQL built-in function [ROW_COUNT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count).

```
mysql> insert into employee (name) values ('harry'), ('ron'), ('hermione');

mysql> select row_count();
+-------------+
| row_count() |
+-------------+
|           3 |
+-------------+
```

But to answer your question, you can do what you're trying to do only with a session variable, not a local variable declared within the trigger. A local variable is local to *each invocation* of the trigger, once for each row. So it can't retain its value from one row to the next. Whereas a session variable is scoped to your current session. You can set a session variable within a trigger, and the value will still be in that variable after your triggers are all done.

```
mysql> create trigger count_inserted_trigger
    after insert on employee
    for each row
    set @count_it  = @count_it + 1;
```

(Notice that a single-statement trigger like this doesn't need a begin/end block, and therefore you don't need to mess around with changing the statement delimiter.)

Initialize the session variable before you do the insert. Then after your insert, it should have the count.

```
mysql> set @count_it = 0;

mysql> insert into employee (name) values ('harry'), ('ron'), ('hermione');

mysql> select @count_it;
+-----------+
| @count_it |
+-----------+
|         3 |
+-----------+
```